# Банковское округление. Шаги

Tags: суммирование

Всем доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой:

Есть, допустим, 10 договоров в долларовой валюте с 2 символами после запятой.
Мы их переводим в рубли, получаем сумму рублям с >2 символами после запятой.
Далее складываем в получаем общую сумму в рублям с >2 символами после запятой.
что не верно.

В какой момент необходимо применять банковское округление? При переводе каждого договора в рубли или только итоговую сумму? Если после запятой больше, чем 2 символами - округлять(банковским методом) с самого последнего числа попарно или брать только последние 3 знака?

P.S. Банковское = Бухгалтерское

Comment: имхо никогда. Округлять только при отображении пользователю, а работать с точными десятичными значениями (decimal - типы)...

Comment: Банки - зло! Придумали единицы измерения меньше копейки :)

Comment: Вам нужно спрашивать у людей, которые занимаются банковским делом, а не программистов.